# How could I customize \titlepage in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

everyone, I have a beamer presentation but now I need to add two logos to the    `\title` page before that the macro    `\title`, but when I add this to the code I get several errors, I think that I have to use the macro `\defbeamertemplate` but I don't know how to add the images and text. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{picture}(18,1)
\put(-26,-67.5){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ipn.png}}
\put(240.5,-70.5){\includegraphics[width=2.1cm]{escom.png}}
\end{picture}

\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\begin{Large}
\\\hspace{1.35cm}Instituto Polit\'ecnico Nacional
\end{Large}}\\}
\hspace{1cm}
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\begin{Large}
Escuela Superior de C\'omputo
\end{Large}}} 

\title{Trabajo Terminal: 2011-0003 SOCPO}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to get something like this:

[image: I would like to get something like this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can locally set the `headline` beamer template  to contain both logos and the Institution name; something along these lines (depending on the logo dimensions you will have to adjust some lengths):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\newcommand\InsName{%
  \parbox{.5\textwidth}{%
  \Large\centering Instituto Polit\'ecnico Nacional\\[1ex]Escuela Superior de C\'omputo}%
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{0.5cm}%
  \hspace*{0.8cm}%
  \rule{.15\textwidth}{1.5cm}% \includegraphics for logo 1 goes here
  \hfill\raisebox{.6cm}{\InsName}\hfill%
  \rule{.15\textwidth}{1.5cm}% \includegraphics for logo 2 goes here
  \hspace*{0.8cm}%
}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which length should change to adjust thes size of the pic? Thanks